# Exclude records which have relation empty/null in Illuminate Eloquent ORM outside laravel

Tags: php, eloquent

**Status - Resolved**

I'm using **Illuminate ORM outside laravel**. So, far working good but I'm having trouble with relation. I want to exclude those records whose **profile** and **accountDetails** relation is **empty** or **null**. Currently I manually extract those fields and create another array and return it but its alot of processing so is there any way where I can put some condition for relation if it is null or empty exclude those records.

Here is my code

```
$users = \App\User::where('account_type_id', 2)
    ->with('profile', 'accountDetails')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

In **User Model**, I've created two relations ie. **profile** and **accountDetails**

```
public function profile()
{           
    return $this->hasOne('\App\UserProfile', 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function accountDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Wallet', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Thanks in Advance. :)

Any help on this please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a join mechanism.

```
$users = \App\User::join('profile','profile.user_id','=','user.id')
    ->join('wallet','wallet.user_id','=','user.id')
    ->where([
        ['user.account_type_id','=',2],
        ['profile.id','=',null],
        ['wallet.id','=',null]
     ])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Joins: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins

---

Second method, using eloquent relations,

On the **User Model**:

```
public function profile() {
    return $this->hasOne('\App\UserProfile', 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function accountDetails(){    
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Wallet', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Then the query:

```
$users = \App\User::where('account_type_id', 2)
    ->has('profile')
    ->has('accountDetails')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

`has` query method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: 2nd method here is the way to go